# E key gets stuck in games (Windows)

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10

I should note that E is the physical key on the keyboard; I use Dvorak so the character the key enters is actually ".". I also use ESDF instead of WSAD, so E is my forwards-key (like W in WSAD). I'm on a laptop so there's no issues with a USB keyboard.

In games like Minecraft and SMITE, it gets stuck sometimes. I continue running forward for maybe three to four seconds, then stop. Sometimes it also doesn't work anymore and I can't go forward for a few seconds. When I open chat in Minecraft, I can't write anything with that key.

It only seems to happen if I hold the key down for a long time (which only happens when I'm gaming, basically). I never had the issue during normal typing and it doesn't happen with other keys it seems.

I have disabled Sticky Keys and I've tried messing with the Filter keys and general keyboard settings to minimize the key repeat rate. It seems to help a little bit (it continues to get "stuck" but not for as long as before) but I still have the issue.

Other people seem to have had similar problems but didn't find a solution.

Comment: What kind of keyboard do you have? Standard keyboard with a rubber membrane? Or is it mechanical?

Comment: probably key jamming/ghosting google "key rollover matrix keyboard". The game probably is not registering the "keyup event" because of the layout of your keyboard matrix.

Answer (score 2):

It's the hardware issue. Happens when that key is pressed too many times. Simply change the keyboard.